# How to encrypt query parameter in Spring Data repository method?

Tags: java, encryption, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

JPA provides the EntityListener/Converter mechanism to transform data during numerous operations.

`@PostLoad` would transform the data as it is returned from the database.

However, this of course doesn't come into play when calling a Spring Data repository method such as `findByAccountNumber(String accountNumber)`.

So, for example, the Account table stores an encrypted account number. When I do a search, the clear text value is passed, thus yielding no result.

Is there a way to intercept the method before it gets called so that the argument being passed is modified prior to the query taking place?

Comment: Where does the encryption take place? If in your service layer you should also encrypt the accountNumber for database search in your service layer.

Comment: No, in the DAO layer. I'm using an EntityListener on my Entity bean.
This is more of a DAO layer operation rather than a service layer operation.

I've just tried the AOP approach, so that the Repository method is advised prior to execution such that the accountNumber is encrypted first.

This should've worked, but alas! It doesn't! :(

Looks like I may be forced to do this in the service layer

Comment: @OliverGierke ? Why did the modified argument not get passed to the repository method, despite calling `pjp.proceed(new Object[] {encryptedArg})` ?

Comment: @OliverGierke ? Seems that the modified argument does get passed to the repository method, after passing through the `Around` advice, and the database log does confirm this. However, the repository method returns null, despite having an `Optional<Account>` response defined. Why? The sql as printed does return a record, so something in Spring is not comfortable with the custom advice on the repository method.